# Apple app store build submission for review in new itunesconnect

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

As apple has changed the itunesconnect interface recently ,I am having problem with submitting the app for review which was previously rejected by Apple.I am unable to find the build which was submitted from Xcode successfully.so I can not submit the app for review again. Can anyone enlighten me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

At last found the option.In itunesconnect going to My app and selecting the desired app takes me to the app page.Then selecting the App store option and after that selecting the rejected binary form the left menu opens the app detail at right ,from there I found the option to add the new build.